# Domain blocked my domain for whois invalid data

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, domain, subdomain, domain-name

My domain name domain.net is download video and converter web site.
Name.com disabled my domain without notice.

I can not transfer my domain. Name.com does not open the transfer lock.
Do not change DNS,Nameserver. What can I do? Sended mail to Name.com but is not answering...

I have used the domain for many years, but blocked now. Do they have the rights?
Name.com have a right to blocked domain?

Transfer lock: Locked
Domain status : ClientHold

Name.com send mail after blocked my domain

> Name.com Email Message
>    DOMAINS. WEBSITES. HOSTING.
>    Locks have been added/remove to one or more of your domains.
>   Hello,Thank you for your support of Name.com. Name.com recently received evidence
>   that the domain(s) referenced below were involved in activities that are in breach
>   of our Registration Agreement. After further review we find that this complaint is
>   valid and the following domain(s) has been placed on registrar-domain.net
>   The suspension was due to the following:This domain has been disabled due to a WDPR
>   Name.com received from ICANN. Please respond to abuse@name.com with the requested
>   information and they are happy to review. If you feel that this action has been made
>   in error, or that the abuse may have been the result of a security compromise,
>   please contact abuse@name.com (mailto:abuse@name.com) with any questions or

Comment: It may be best to get someone on the phone at name.com and get more details.  You would then have to dispute the matter with them and potentially ICANN.  It is up to them to release the lock on your domain.

Comment: Actually no. As Ruscal's answer nicely explains they are not doing that because they want, but because the domain is not following ICANN rules to start with.

Comment: They investigated and found that your domain registration information looks fake. That's why your domain was suspended. You need to provide real information in the domain registration, but you can use a whois privacy service to keep it out of public view.

Comment: Thank you, icann mailled to me but unused mail, Really thank you for all

Answer (score 5):

According to the email you received, the abuse team at Name.com received a WDPR (Whois Data Problem Report) that was submitted through ICANN.  These reports are used to identify incomplete or inaccurate WHOIS data, and the registrar is required to take action to verify/complete the WHOIS data once a report is received.  Name.com's policy includes holding the domain during an investigation and until they are satisfied with the accuracy of entries.

I see that the domain is listed as being registered to one Johannes Truda of Luxemborg [sic].  If this is your real identity, then you should contact the abuse@name.com email address to provide the verification information they need.  If this is a pseudonym, then you will need to update your account and WHOIS information to reflect either a real person or real organization; then contact the abuse@name.com address to provide the verification information.

In the end, Name.com took action because of [what they believe to be] a substantiated report of inaccurate WHOIS information.  The domain name is still registered until 2018, but they have put it in status clientHold which removes it from DNS publication until the issue is resolved.  Follow the directions in the email they sent you and you should be able to find out the root of the problem and how to fix it.

***TLDR ::*** Follow the directions in the notice Name.com sent you, contact their abuse@name.com email address to provide the requested verification and/or get more information.

Comment: As pointed out by others, you can maintain anonymity by using a whois proxy or privacy service as the "Real Organization" that your domain is registered to.

Comment: Thank you, icann mailled to me but unused mail, Really thank you for all. info@site.com